# Strange Behaviour of tabbarcontroller

Tags: iphone, tabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar application and i am encountering a strange behaviour....when i toggle the tab bar and reaches into new view controllers sometimes the viewDidLoad of these view controllers are getting called...though viewDidLoad should get called only first time...
can anyone tell...any suggestion??

Comment: Do you mean when you go in, then come back out and go in again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's  a low memory warning then a tab bar controller will release all views that are not visible. This means that you can get viewDidLoad called more than once because the view has been unloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Is your app memory-intensive, perhaps to the point that you're receiving memory warning? Though I have not experienced the behavior you're describing, it's possible that due to heavy memory use your unseen views are being released due to a lack of memory. When they're next called into view they would need to be reinitialized, calling `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Hah, you beat me to the answer by 26 seconds :)

Comment: this could be the reason...but when i run my application...memory usage never exceeds 6 MB...

Comment: @deanWombourne Sometimes later is better: you got credit for the answer. :)

Comment: Yea, that is odd - your answer is better :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's viewDidLoad, not viewWillAppear?

viewDidLoad will only be called once in each UIViewController subclass, so if your layout is like this:

```
-UITabBarController:
    - HappyUIViewController
    - SadUIViewController
    - ThirdUIViewController
```

Then viewDidLoad will be called three times. Once for HappyUIViewController, once for SadUiViewController, and so on.